# Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202)

Tags: http, proxy, isaserver

I am getting above error in some machines but not in some machines while accessing the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information in your question might help, but after a quick google I found [this forum](http://forums.isaserver.org/fb.aspx?m=2002054360) which may answer your question (there appears to be a hotfix that may help).

Comment: Thanks, actually in a single network from some machines I am able to access the documents present in a website correctly but from some machines for other users not able to, they are getting this error 502

Answer (score 1):

Open the `ISA server2006` and create a role and allow networks internal to allow internal and external.

Restart isa services, and it will be work fine.